# I am getting ConcurrentModificationException while creating a chat application

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

While displaying the recent chats fragment in the application I am fetching my chats from firebase and filtering out the chats by their receiverID and senderID in the chat object to display the recent chats.

The problem says ConcurrentModificationException in ArrayList and it looks like due to the complexity of searching id in the array it occurred, I need a solution to minimize this chat filteration complexity.

```
  // private List<String> stringList; Declaration at top 
    stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BaatCheet/Chats/");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //userModelList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                MessageModel messageModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MessageModel.class);

                if (messageModel.getSender().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                  stringList.add(messageModel.getReceiver());
                }
                if (messageModel.getReceiver().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                    stringList.add(messageModel.getSender());
                }
            }
            readChat();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

The read chat function

```
  private void readChat() {

    userModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BaatCheet/Users/");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userModelList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserModel.class);

                for (String id: stringList){
                    if (userModel.getId().equals(id)){
                        if (userModelList.size() !=0){
                            for (UserModel userModel1 : userModelList){
                                if (!userModel.getId().equals(userModel1.getId())){
                                    userModelList.add(userModel);
                                    Log.d("DataAdded",userModel.getId());
                                } // If the existing list don't have same value for sender and reciever
                            } // end of inner userModel
                        } else {
                            userModelList.add(userModel);
                            Log.d("DataAdded",userModel.getId());
                        } // end of else
                    }   // end of userModel id equals string id
                }   // end of String is loop
            }   // end of DataSnapshot loop

            usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(userModelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);


        } // end of onDataChange

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}// end of readChat()
```

The results would be the recyclerView of recent chats containing the chats which contain messages either send by the sender or receiver to each other.

Comment: The MessageModel object contains 3 values 
{
  "message" : "hi",
  "receiver" : "OiMmgOLTPhdgcizouU9ylHhiXRV2",
  "sender" : "piXG0LgakVYD3bnlhbYqecCdiOw1"
}

Answer (score 1):

In the following snippet of code :

```
for (UserModel userModel1 : userModelList){
   if (!userModel.getId().equals(userModel1.getId())){
        userModelList.add(userModel);
        Log.d("DataAdded",userModel.getId());
    } // If the existing list don't have same value for sender and reciever
} //
```

You are modifying userModelList while iterating through userModelList. This is not allowed and is the cause of `ConcurrentModificationException`.

There are few ways to simplify the logic, the simplest (albeit not the best) would be to convert this `foreach` loop into a simple `for i` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i< userModelList.size(); i++) {
    UserModel userModel1 = userModelList.get(i);
    if (!userModel.getId().equals(userModel1.getId())){
       userModelList.add(userModel);
       Log.d("DataAdded",userModel.getId());
    } // If the existing list don't have same value for sender and reciever
} //
```

Comment: Thanks since I got the solution by changing the system of searching from all chats by creating a seperate node for the recent chat list.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to handle this complexity I am now using separate nodes just for storing the chatLists as such now I don't need to read chats for filtering the recent chats.

The below code is for creating a new node everytime user sends a message it will update the node if the recieverID is different.

```
dbrefChatList = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                getReference("BaatCheet/ChatList/")
                .child(senderuserID)
                .child(receiveruserID);

        dbrefChatList.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    dbrefChatList.child("id").setValue(receiveruserID);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

As such ChatList is a Model Class which contains single String called "id" and this id    will be used to search in the node.

The below code is for the ChatFragment which fetches the chatList from firebase and set the data to recycler view.

```
      // private List<ChatList> chatList; Declaration at top
    chatListList = new ArrayList<>();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference("BaatCheet/ChatList")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid());

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            chatListList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ChatList chatList = snapshot.getValue(ChatList.class);
                    chatListList.add(chatList);
                }
                myChatList();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

The function myChatList act as the function of readChat in the problem statement.

```
 private void myChatList() {

    userModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BaatCheet/Users/");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userModelList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                for (ChatList chatList : chatListList){
                    if (userModel.getId().equals(chatList.getId())){
                        userModelList.add(userModel);
                    }
                }
            }
            usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(userModelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag while traversing the array, after it's done, add it if it doesn't exist yet:

```
// Display 1 user from chats
for (String id : str_usersList) {
    if (user.getId().equals(id)) {
        if (userList.size() != 0) {
            boolean exists = false;
            // If not exists then add
            for (User user1 : userList) {
                if (user.getId().equals(user1.getId())) {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exists) {
                userList.add(user);
            }
        } else {
            userList.add(user);
        }
    }
}
```